# Where does the last newline character come from in this sed's result?

Tags: sed, newlines

I'm learning sed's different commands and did some experiments. The command I'm trying is:

```
root:[~]# seq 7 | sed -n '1~2H; 2~2{G;p}'
2

1
4

1
3
6

1
3
5
root:[~]#
```

I analyzed the command and to me the last newline character after the number `5` should not exist. Below is my analysis.

[image]

Based on my analysis, the output should be the cells with the red color background. As you can see, there is no last newline character. Where am I wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a newline as last character. Did you paste the wrong screenshot?

Comment: If there is no newline, the last line should look like "5root:[~]#"

Comment: You can verify by increasing your `seq` to 8. You'll see that there's no newline after 5.

Comment: If `p` did not add a newline to its output, the simple `sed` command `sed -n p` would concatenate all lines of input. Also, please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Why are you fine with a newline after the first `1` (before the `4`), but not with the newline after the `5`? It's the same mechanism.

Comment: Thanks @TobySpeight, I'll remember that. I've modified the question based on your suggestion.

Comment: @Philippos I think you are right. I overlooked them.

Comment: Something is not a line of text in UNIX *unless* it ends with a newline. Unlike Windows, where newlines *separate* lines, on UNIX, newlines *terminate* lines, so data without a newline is not part of a well-formed line in a text file on UNIX -- which explains the "why" behind the specification you found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`p` adds the newline character:

```
% printf 1 | sed 'p;s/1/2/'
1
2%
```

As can be seen, the `2` is printed without a trailing newline, but the 1 before it, from `p`, is.

Comment: Note that the implicit print at the end of the cycle in a non-GNU `sed` may also add a newline, even if there was no newline in the input (a non-terminated line is not actually valid input to standard `sed`).

Answer (score 6):

I think I found the answer. From the POSIX sed's documentation at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html, it states:

> Whenever the pattern space is written to standard output or a named file, sed shall immediately follow it with a newline.

That means the `p` command will always print pattern space as well as a newline. That also explains why there are newlines after `2\n\n1`, `4\n\n1\n3` and `6\n\n1\n3\n5`.

Please correct me if you think there is anything wrong with this. Thank you.

Comment: Exactly. That's it.